# Pandas df.read_html dropping duplicate tables in html

Tags: python, pandas, html-table, duplicates

I have a html file locally with multiple tables. Sometimes the content of the table is exactly the same including headers. While reading it through pandas I have noticed that when two tables are exactly identical it will drop the second one as if it is not there. When I change one `<td>Value</td>` value in the second table it will read the second table also and display.

How can i stop pandas doing that and read every table

Attaching the exact HTML file. If you see there are 4 tables. Still I get only 3 tables values. The big 2 two tables have exact same data and it is publishing only first one

```
import pandas as pd
tables = pd.read_html('D:\\myhtml.html', header=0)
print (tables)
```

The file is uploaded to a third party site as html snippet is too big

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5HhBthFvDrtMWNtRDBhS1lQcGM/view?usp=sharing